# redux-form: handlesSubmit returns empty form values when one of the fields are file

Tags: react-native, redux-form

When I fill the form with my data it is successfully adds it to redux state

[image: redux form values]

If I do not fill the images field then values are returned correctly with handleSubmit.

When I add image to images field then it updates values state and for some reason initial state. And handleSubmit only returns this image field from initial state and empty on other fields.

Answer (score 0):

The problem code was in this function where I was updating existing images value.

```
let updatedImages = this.props.images.input.value;
updatedImages.push(...images);
this.props.images.input.onChange(updatedImages);
```

Solution:

```
let updatedImages = [...this.props.images.input.value];
updatedImages.push(...images);
this.props.images.input.onChange(updatedImages);
```